# PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 1920x1080

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, detection, raspbian

This is my code to detect circle/balls.
I want to detect soccer ball from Pi camera. (soccer ball could be in any color.) I am having trouble with some PiCameraValueError. What is wrong with this code. I am using Raspberry Pi 2, Python2, and OpenCV.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import sys
import imutils
import cv2.cv as cv
# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr"):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array
    img   = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)
    imgg  = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    cimg  = cv2.cvtColor(imgg, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    imgg  = cv2.blur(imgg, (3,3))
            #imgg = cv2.dilate(imgg, np.ones((5, 5)))
            #imgg = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgg,(5,5),0)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imgg, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=100, param2=40, minRadius=5, maxRadius=90)
    cv2.imshow("cimg", imgg)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if circles is None:
        continue

    print circles
            #circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1) # draw the outer circle
                   #cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3) # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.imshow("Filtered", cimg)

cv2.destroyWindow("cimg")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera),

> the `PiCameraValueError` is a secondary exception raised in response to
>   the KeyboardInterrupt exception. This is quite normal and not a bug
>   (it's more a consequence of how generic the output mechanism is in
>   picamera), but it is difficult to detect and respond to in Python 2
>   (the usual method there would probably be to catch the
>   PiCameraValueError as well in whatever loop your main script runs).
>   Under Python 3, [exception chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414744/python-exception-chaining) is implemented so you could
>   potentially look back through the stack of exceptions to find the
>   KeyboardInterrupt one.

What you need to do is clear the stream between captures. The [PiRGBArray](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.7/array.html#picamera.array.PiRGBArray) docs cover doing this with truncate function.

Here is an example from, [python face detection raspberry pi with picamera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938829/python-face-detection-raspberry-pi-with-picamera)

```
import io
import time
import picamera
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format='jpeg'):
    # YOURS:  for frame in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format="bgr",  use_video_port=True):
        # Truncate the stream to the current position (in case
        # prior iterations output a longer image)
        stream.truncate()
        stream.seek(0)
        if process(stream):
            break
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having trouble with this code for ball detection. I have different type of soccer balls.